# What is __rw::__rw_deallocate?

Tags: c++, boost, arm

I have an ARM application in which I occasionally get data abort or prefetch abort crash reports with

```
__rw::__rw_deallocate(void*, unsigned int, int)
```

at the top of the stack.  What is this function and who owns it?  Google turns up various linker and build errors related to this function, but my issues are runtime crashes.  I use both boost and std libraries in my application.

Comment: Since it has two sequential underscores one can assume it's provided by and specific to the compiler/library implementation.

Comment: I am going to guess that getting errors here is caused by writing passed the end of a buffer and when your vendor's deallocation routines are called, they fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an implementation detail (`__*` are library reserved names) for heap functions (malloc, free etc.).

The fact it crashes there usually means you invoke [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by doing

- a double free
- a free of an unitialized (*inderminate*) pointer
- you have a race condition doing such things

etc.

Is threading involved? (check your locking)

If not, check for out-of-bounds addressing, uninitialized variable access etc.

Tools like `valgrind` are highly instrumental here.

Comment: Threading is involved.  The particular crash I'm worried about is happening in a handler for inter-thread messages containing weak pointers and other data.